# How Hadoop calculate physical memory and virtual memory during a job execution

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I have few queries related to the counters used in Hadoop to display memory usage.
A map reduce job executed on a cluster gives me below menitoned counter values. Input file used is just in KBs, but these counter shows 35GB and 420 GB usage.
PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES=35110662144
VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES=420121841664

For another different job on same input file it shows 309 MB (physical) and 3G(vitual) usage

PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES=309526528
VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES=3435827200

First job is more CPU intensive than other and creates more objects than the other one but still its usage shown seems very high. 
So I just wanted to know how this memory usage is calculated. I tried going through some posts and gave an over view on this below link which seems to be 
requirement task for describing these variables (https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/MAPREDUCE-1218 ) but couldnt find how these are calculated. It does gives me an idea on how these values are passed to Job Tracker,but no information on how these are determined. So if some one could give some insight on this than it would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can find few references [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html#manually_configure_memory_settings) and [here](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Resource+Allocation+for+Jobs+and+Applications). The second link in particular to map and reducer job and how slots are decided based on memory allocations. Happy Learning